# How to fix the following form submit code?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Page URL:

```
 http://website.net/page
```

Output in address bar after submit:

```
http://website.net/page?paste=text
```

I want the result to look like this:

```
http://website.net/page?text
```

Without the name of the input appearing

Is there a way to do that?

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<?php
$u = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

$n = '/paste?\D(.+]?)/';

preg_match($n, $u, $n);

$url = "$n[1]";

echo $url;
?>

<form id="a">
<input type="text" id="paste" name="paste" maxlength="5" size="5" onchange="submit()">
</form>
```

Comment: Change form method to post eg. form method="POST". And if you want, you can add action: form method="POST" action="page?text">

Comment: Instead of this line? <form id="a">

Comment: Yep, just add it as attributes of form: <form id="a" method="POST" action="page?text"> And if you handle this form somewhere, you need to change the way you retrieve data if you use $_GET change it to $_POST

Comment: Arosha De Silva No, its not what ive asked.

Comment: @Eakethet ok great, i did: <form id="a" method="POST" action="page?$url"> but the string not displayed. How do I continue?

Comment: Query strings, which is what appears after the ?, are expected to be key value pairs.  As such what you are asking for is not a 'fix', but a breaking of this standard

Comment: @macks Well, depends on what you want to display? If you want to display value from input, use echo $_POST['paste'];

Comment: @Eakethet how sould i put the echo? i tried this: <form id="a" method="POST" action="page?echo $_POST['paste'];">

Comment: @macks Replace you echo $url with echo $_POST['paste']. I will try to write down snippet as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this...

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<?php
$u = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$n = '/paste?\D(.+]?)/';
preg_match($n, $u, $n);
$url = "$n[1]";
echo $url;
// Check if is set
if (isset($_POST['paste'])) {
    // Echo input value
    echo $_POST['paste'];
}
// Change method to post
?>
<form id="a" method="POST">
    <input type="text" id="paste" name="paste" maxlength="5" size="5" onchange="submit()">
</form>
```

Comment: some error Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{' line 10

Comment: yep, sorry, forgot ")" in if statement, fixed

Comment: I think it does not add the query to the address bar, but I'm still checking

Comment: I made some code changes, and now works :) Thank you very much!